# App Transport Security NOT Working for .ninja domain names (Swift2 / XCode7)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7, app-transport-security

Using XCode7/Swift2 and trying to load a webpage, I keep getting blocked by App Transport Security (ATS) -- and the reason seems to be that ATS doesn't work for the .ninja web extension.

Meaning, you can add an exception for `domains.com` and you can go to this site in a webview. But, you cannot add an exception for `domains.ninja`, although this is a valid web address. I have tested this out fully.

Right now the only way I am able to load content from somewebsite.ninja is if I completely turn ATS off in my Info.plist file (NSAppTransportSecurity > NSAllowsArbitraryLoads > YES), but I know this isn't the right way to do things. I'm also worried that this may cause issues when I submit my app to the app store when it's done.

Does anyone know how to add an exception to ATS for the .ninja domain?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>domains.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>domains.ninja</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

The above will allow you to load up domains.com but not domains.ninja in a webview, even though the keys/options are exactly the same other than the domain name extension.

Comment: Can you show the entries you are putting in your info.plist and the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: yes, just edited answer. please note that I'm just using espn.com just as a test case. i have also tested using a different domain name i.e. `somedomain.ninja` with same results. the only way so far around it is to disable ATS altogether

Comment: For me https:// www.espn.ninja doesn't connect and http:// espn.ninja is a parked domain

Comment: then try any other .ninja domain, it shouldn't matter that it's parked. In fact, I should have used another example. try these two domains instead:  `http://domains.ninja/` and `http://domains.com` -- these are both valid sites. as well as the espn sites above (even though one is parked it still is valid, and I'm testing with a valid non-parked website anyway)

Comment: "I'm also worried that this may cause issues when I submit my app to the app store when it's done." What issues would it cause? Arbitrary Loads is _legal_. That is what it is _for_. Use it and move on. And file a bug report. This is not your problem. Apple got themselves into this mess; it's their job to deal with it.

Comment: thanks @matt, this will be my first app submission to the app store so i just want to have all my ducks in a row before trying. it really helps though to hear from you that turning off ATS shouldn't be an issue. I'm assuming you've had no trouble getting an app approved with ATS completely disabled. thanks

Comment: Your .ninja domains are http - not https, so the exceptions you have specified are not sufficient.  You need to set `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` to true but there is no issue with disabling ATS as far as app submission goes.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not sure you are correct here. I fully understand that I'm not using HTTPS but using HTTP, however if you look above I do have a key called `NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` set to true. It's slightly different from the key name you provided but I believe is the correct one for Swift2/Xcode7 as this code fully works and let's me view websites over http as long as the extension is .com. Doesn't work for .ninja. HTTPS vs HTTP is a non-issue for me since the exceptions I provided above work fine for http but only for .com extensions

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the extra key `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` however adding this key still blocks .ninja address even after adding it and restarting. I think this is a BUG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the `domains.ninja` page to load in a `UIWebView` but I had to include all of the other domains that the page referenced - various analytics, CDN and tracking sites.

The excerpt from my info.plist is -

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>domains.ninja</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>www.geoplugin.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>marketo.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>googleapis.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>netdna.bootstrapcdn.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>www.google-analytics.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>mktoresp.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>gstatic.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

So, in the end it is probably simpler to just turn ATS off in general and add exceptions for domains that do support TLS.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11, this would make sense that perhaps it's not blocking my specific .ninja domain rather my page may  referencing other domains so the whole page is blocked. Whatever the case I am disabling ATS altogether because it's too much of a problem and I need to have dynamic web views loaded in my app. I haven't tested fully yet but this gives me insight